# перегрузка оператора ()(int,int)

Tags: c++, строки, ооп, объекты, перегрузка-операторов

для класса String требуется перегрузить несколько операторов,возник вопрос с перегрузкой оператора ()(int,int) -возвращение подстроки объекта.Как это можно реализовать?

```
class MyString
{
    private:
    char *str;
    size_t size;
    public:

    MyString();
    MyString(const char *str);
    ~MyString();

    void Print();
    int Length();

    MyString operator ()(int,int);
    void operator +=(const MyString &other);

    MyString(const MyString &other);

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MyString other);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &stream, MyString &other);
};
```

Comment: Вполне приличная задача. Рады за вас.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator

Comment: @Harry прошу отвечать только по теме)

Comment: @Abyx это одна из частей,с которой возникли вопросы,именно поэтому и был задан вопрос

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в посте вопроса. С чем именно трудность?

Comment: @Abyx скажите пожалуйста как Вы определили что это домашнее задание ?

Comment: @Abyx спасибо что ответили на вопрос

Comment: Вы понимаете, как создать подстроку из C-строки? Вот в операторе ее и создайте - вплоть до просто перенося нужные символы по одному в новую строку MyString. Ее и возвращайте...

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как у вас хранится строка (size ее длина или зазмер выделенной памяти, непонятно, как считать конец подстроки - что второй аргумент указывает на последний символ подстроки или за подстроку. Я считаю, что на последний символ подстроки.

Тогда получается так:

```
MyString operator ()(int b,int e) {
    if (b < 0 || e < 0 || b > e || e >= strlen(str)) throw exception("Неверные данные");
    char * s = new char[e-b+2];
    for(int i = b; i <= e; i++) s[i-b] = str[i];
    s[e-b+1] = 0;
    MyString ret(s);
    delete[]s;
    return ret;
    }
```